# HttpSessionState returns HTML entity instead of character

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A JavaScript function tries to use a string value that was stored in HttpSessionState; the string value also contains Swedish characters (e.g. consider the word MJÖLBY). The problem is that the special character is appeared as an HTML entity `&#246;` instead of the real character. I tried to fix this by using encoding, but unfortunately it did not help and the result of encoding is *undefined*. Is there any idea how to pass **Ö** instead of entity code `&#246;` for using in JavaScript and before publishing on the browser?

**Update:**
In `Session_Start()`, the string is set by `Session["City"] = "MJÖLBY";`  and then in JavaScript the value is being read by `var city = @Session["City"].ToString();`

Comment: How do you get that value from session into javascript? Could you add that code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` parameter in Razor does HTML encoding. So it's normal that `Ö` is converted to its HTML entity. If you want to achieve that use could use the `Html.Raw` method. Also make sure that you are properly JSON encoding your strings or you will get pretty broken javascript if the value in your session is for example `MJÖ'LBY`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var city = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["City"]));
</script>
```

Comment: @Darvin Dimitrov Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I just changed it a bit like this `var city = '@Html.Raw(Session["City"])';`

Comment: No, **DON'T DO THIS**!!!! If the value of `Session["City"]` is `MJÖ'LBY`, guess what you will end up with in your markup: a totally broken javascript: `var city = 'MJÖ'LBY';`. Not to mention the terrible XSS attack you will be vulnerable to if this input was coming from a user. You absolutely always want to JSON encode anything you are throwing at your javascript that comes from the server.